# ProgressBar won't show up, after second click on button, which provides api call response

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, mvvm, android-livedata

I have an app, where user provide some data. After checking if the provided data is valid, the app should perform an api call, and then, display the response. User can do it multiple times.

To be more specific - assume, that we have an edit text, and button. User provide some data in edit text, and then, click on `button`. If data provided in `EditText` is valid, then perform an api call with using provided data, and display it in the `TextView`.

The `ProgressBar` is visible withing the `setOnClickListener` in `button`. After making an api call, observing `LiveData` from `ViewModel`, and displaying it in `TextView`, the `ProgressBar` is set to `INVISIBLE`. Until now, everything is working as intended. Now, when user decide to slighlty change the data, and perform another api call, the `ProgressBar` won't show up.

**Button**

```
myBinding.apiCall.setOnClickListener {
        myBinding.TestProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        TestJob.start()
}
```

**Job**

```
  private val TestJob: Job
        get() = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
            TestVM.MakeApiCall()

            TestVM.ApiResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { apiresult ->
                when (apiresult) {
                    is TestWrapper.Success -> {
                        myBinding.MyTextView.text = String.format(
                            getString(R.string.testString),
                            it
                        )
                        myBinding.TestProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    }

                    is TestWrapper.Error -> {}
                }
            })
        }
```

I've tried to make a `delay`, in `Observable`, and the `ProgressBar` appeared. How it can be, that after first time it appeared, but after that, it won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

With each click you are starting completely new coroutine that will observe ApiResponse forever*.

When you click second time:

- You show progress bar
- You start API call
- The value in API response is still success from previous call.
- You start observing successful result.
- You hide the progress bar
- The result from the second call updates the UI.

There is more to be said but this is the gist.

Comment: Does making the data in ViewModel nullable, and after receiving the response in Observe, and calling the value to null, is considered good practice? It does solve the problem, but I don't think that is the way that I should solve it.